# Compare two table different amount mysql query

Tags: mysql, comparison

Compare two tables sum mysql query

I have two tables...

fee_prescribed_amount  table values....

---

```
customer_no       `prscribed_sales_amount`       `purchase item  ` `group id`
  1                     25000                      laptop               101
  1                      5000                       mouse               101
  2                      4000                      Keyboard            501
  2                      6000                     mobile               501
```

fee_collection  table values

---

```
customer_no       `group id`      `received_amt`       
    1                101             20000              
    1                101              3000            
    2                501               1000
    2                501              8000
```

output need following

```
customer no     `prscribed_sales_amount minus(-) received_amt`  `group id`   

   1                    7000                                     101
   2                    1000                                      501
```

one customer buy electonic items grouped product. that customer give money in two installment.now need how much amount is pending?

example one customer buy laptop 25000+mouse 5000 total bill amt 30000

but that customer give amount two installment 20000+3000 total received amount is 23000 now need balance for grouped item is 7000. for that need mysql query

Comment: And what's the question? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: what did you try so far?